# Are legal questions (AI act) on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering if specific questions about the AI act are on topic here ? or are they better suited for a legal SE ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say they'd probably be more suitable on legal SE, because I feel like answering such questions correctly would often require much more legal expertise than expertise of the inner workings of AI. But I would be open to being persuaded if our community at large disagrees.

Comment: Well in essence my problem is the text is "too legal", that is it feels like not enough experts were involved. And it is difficult to see how practitioners would implement it, or how practical example would comply.

Comment: I guess it would also depend on the specifics of your question. If your question is more like "please explain what this article in the law means?", that's probably a legal question. However, if it's more like "here is my own, dummy-friendly summary of one of the articles in this act. How could contemporary AI training approach X be adapted to actually follow this new law?"... I imagine that would probably fit better on AI.SE.

Comment: I have started posting my question and somehow managed to get a clear sepration between what should be asked here and on Law SE. Also got an answer to my question here: AI SE has a legal tag, so answer is yes.